# Poincaré-type inequality from an article

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces

At some point in [this article](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~alaptev/Papers/lw.pdf), the following lemma is applied.

**Lemma**

> If $u\in H^1(\alpha,\beta),u(\beta)=0,\beta>\alpha\geq0$, then:
>
> $$\int_\alpha^\beta|u(r)|^2rdr\leq2^{-1}(\beta-\alpha)^2\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(r)|^2rdr.$$

I tried three different routes, and got three different inequalities, each of which differs from the above. Here goes.

**Route 1**

\begin{align*}
\int_\alpha^\beta|u(r)|^2rdr\overset\ast={}&\int_\alpha^\beta\left|\int_\beta^ru'(s)ds\right|^2rdr\overset{J}{\leq}\int_\alpha^\beta\int_r^\beta|u'(s)|^2rdsdr\leq{} \\
{}\leq{}&\int_\alpha^\beta\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2rdsdr=\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2ds\cdot\int_\alpha^\beta rdr={} \\
{}={}&\frac12(\beta^2-\alpha^2)\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2ds.
\end{align*}

J is [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality), $\ast$ is because $H^1$ functions in 1 dimension are absolutely continuous so $u(r)-u(\beta)=\int_\beta^ru'(s)ds$ and $u(\beta)=0$. Problem: $r$ disappeared from the integrand.

**Route 2**

This is a modification of the above which manages to keep the $r$ (or rather, the $s$), but the constant is still not the right one.

\begin{align*}
\int_\alpha^\beta|u(r)|^2rdr\overset\ast={}&\int_\alpha^\beta\left|\int_\beta^ru'(s)ds\right|^2rdr\overset{J}{\leq}\int_\alpha^\beta\int_r^\beta|u'(s)|^2rdsdr\leq{} \\
{}\overset\star\leq{}&\int_\alpha^\beta\int_r^\beta|u'(s)|^2sdsdr\leq\int_\alpha^\beta\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sdsdr={} \\
{}={}&\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sds\cdot\int_\alpha^\beta 1dr={} \\
{}={}&(\beta-\alpha)\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sds.
\end{align*}

Basically I just figured out I could end up with the right integrand if I exploited the fact that we are integrating where $r\leq s$, which is what justifies $\star$, while J and $\ast$ are the same as above.

**Route 3**

\begin{align*}
\int_\alpha^\beta|u(r)|^2rdr={}&\int_\alpha^\beta|u(r)\sqrt r|^2dr\overset\ast=\int_\alpha^\beta\left|\int_\beta^r\frac{d}{dr}(u\sqrt r)|_s\right|^2dr\leq{} \\
{}\overset{J}{\leq}{}&\int_\alpha^\beta\int_r^\beta\left|u'(s)\sqrt s+\frac{u(s)}{\sqrt s}\right|^2dsdr=\int_\alpha^\beta\int_r^\beta\left|\frac{2u'(s)s+u(s)}{2\sqrt s}\right|^2dsdr\leq{} \\
{}\overset\ast\leq{}&\int_\alpha^\beta\int_r^\beta\frac12\left(\left|\frac{u'(s)s}{\sqrt s}\right|^2+\left|\frac{u(s)}{\sqrt s}\right|^2\right)dsdr\leq{} \\
{}\leq{}&\int_\alpha^\beta\frac12\left(|u'(s)|^2s+\frac{|u(s)|^2}{s}\right)dsdr={} \\
{}={}&\frac12(\beta-\alpha)\int_\alpha^\beta\left(|u'(s)|^2+\frac{|u(s)|^2}{s}\right)ds.
\end{align*}

J is as above, $\ast$ is as above ($u(r)\sqrt r$ is Sobolev because $r$ is smooth and $u$ is Sobolev), $\star$ is the convexity of squaring.

How do I get the article's inequality though?

**Update**

As pointed out by @MichałMiśkiewicz in the comments, I made a mistake in all three routes: Jensen's inequality only works for probability spaces, so I have to have an integral over a probability space in order to apply it. Here is the correct version of Route 2:

\begin{align*}
\int_\alpha^\beta|u(r)|^2rdr\overset\ast={}&\int_\alpha^\beta\left|\int_\beta^ru'(s)ds\right|^2rdr={} \\
{}={}&\int_\alpha^\beta\left|(\beta-\alpha)\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\int_\beta^ru'(s)ds\right|^2rdr\leq{} \\
{}\overset{J}{\leq}{}&\int_\alpha^\beta(\beta-\alpha)^2\left(\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\int_r^\beta|u'(s)|^2rds\right)dr\leq{} \\
{}\overset\star\leq{}&(\beta-\alpha)\int_\alpha^\beta\int_r^\beta|u'(s)|^2sdsdr\leq{} \\
{}\leq{}&(\beta-\alpha)\int_\alpha^\beta\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sdsdr={} \\
{}={}&(\beta-\alpha)\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sds\cdot\int_\alpha^\beta 1dr={} \\
{}={}&(\beta-\alpha)^2\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sds.
\end{align*}

In general, what changes is I get an extra factor of $\beta-\alpha$. However, this gets me a missing $\frac12$ in Route 2, and an extra $\beta+\alpha$ I would like to get rid of from Route 1. So how do I solve this?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the application of Jensen's inequality (it works for probability measures, so you need to add some constant).

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Whoops! So I multiply and divide inside the modulus squared by the length of the interval, I take one out as a square, and the other one turns the inside integral to one over a prob space, to which I apply Jensen, which leaves me with only $\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}$ as a factor, and simplifying with the $(\beta-\alpha)^2$ that came out before, I get the extra $\beta-\alpha$ I was missing in Route 2.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz actually there is still a missing $\frac12$. See Update.

Comment: What if you multiply and divide by $\beta-r$ instead of $\beta-\alpha$?

Comment: How dumb of me :). OK, now I got the inequality @mickep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mickep pointed out, I have tu multiply and divide by $\beta-r$, not $\beta-\alpha$. So finally here is the proof of that inequality:

\begin{align*}
\int_\alpha^\beta|u(r)|^2rdr\overset\ast={}&\int_\alpha^\beta\left|\int_\beta^ru'(s)ds\right|^2rdr={} \\
{}={}&\int_\alpha^\beta\left|(\beta-r)\frac{1}{\beta-r}\int_\beta^ru'(s)ds\right|^2rdr\leq{} \\
{}\overset{J}{\leq}{}&\int_\alpha^\beta(\beta-r)^2\left(\frac{1}{\beta-r}\int_r^\beta|u'(s)|^2rds\right)dr\leq{} \\
{}\overset\star\leq{}&\int_\alpha^\beta(\beta-r)\int_r^\beta|u'(s)|^2sdsdr\leq{} \\
{}\leq{}&\int_\alpha^\beta(\beta-r)\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sdsdr={} \\
{}={}&\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sds\cdot\int_\alpha^\beta(\beta-r)dr={} \\
{}={}&-\frac12(\beta-r)^2|_r^\beta\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sds={} \\
{}={}&\frac12(\beta-\alpha)^2\int_\alpha^\beta|u'(s)|^2sds,
\end{align*}

just what we wanted. QED

Comment: Just one additional comment. I did not read the paper, but the inequality is not optimal. To get the optimal estimate one would have to estimate a zero of a certain combination of Bessel functions, which seems difficult to do.